# ¿Como obtener string específicos de una cadena?

Tags: c#, string

En mi app, recibo una cadena
    2:35:1F:99:0C:01:00:4C:00:01:2B:3E:0C:00:02:00:02:00:00:00:E7:03:07:00:61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45:02:01:00:00:00:00

En esta cadena de arriba, hay valores fijos y dinámicos. Lo que necesito saber es cómo obtener lo que esta entre `:00:` y `:02:01:` (valores fijos) al final. Osea `61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45` (valor dinámico). El análisis de la cadena debe realizarse de derecha a izquierda.

Comment: ¿Tu análisis debe ir de derecha a izquierda, cierto? Porque sino el resultado sería `"4C:00:01:2B:3E:0C:00:02:00:02:00:00:00:E7:03:07:00:61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45"`

Comment: Hay :E7:03:07:00:  :E7:03: Fijo luego viene :07: que es dinamico y el :00: luego viene todo el  61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45 y al final el fijo :02:01:

Comment: Si evalúas la cadena de izquierda a derecha, sería encontrar el primer valor fijo `"00"` que está aquí: `"2:35:1F:99:0C:01:00:4C"` y luego el siguiente valor fijo `"02:01"` sería el que se encuentra casi al final: `"54:45:02:01:00:00:00:00"`. Por ende, se tomaría todo el contenido entre esos dos. De estar incorrecto, te pido por favor expliques más sobre el análisis que se debe realizar sobre la cadena.

Comment: Perdon entonces debe ir de derecha a izq. Encontrando el valor "02:01" y luego el ":00:" asi se obtendria el valor dinamico "61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si el análisis de la cadena debe realizarse de derecha a izquierda, propondría un método como este:

```
    private String extraerValor(String cadena, String stringInicial, String stringFinal){
        int terminaString = cadena.LastIndexOf(stringFinal);
        String nuevoString = cadena.Substring(0, terminaString);
        int offset = stringInicial.Length;
        int iniciaString = nuevoString.LastIndexOf(stringInicial) + offset;                      
        int cortar = nuevoString.Length - iniciaString;
        nuevoString = nuevoString.Substring(iniciaString, cortar);            
        return nuevoString;
    }
```

Este es un ejemplo:

```
String s = "2:35:1F:99:0C:01:00:4C:00:01:2B:3E:0C:00:02:00:02:00:00:00:E7:03:07:00:61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45:02:01:00:00:00:00";
Console.WriteLine("Mi String final es: " + extraerValor(s, ":00:", ":02:01:"));
```

teniendo como salida:

```
"Mi String final es: 61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45"
```

Comment: Mismo comentario que a B.Shay: no sé si sea relevante evaluar que "00" se encuentre antes de "02:01".

Comment: Si, primero se evalúa donde esta el string final "02:01", se corta el string desde el inicio hasta ese punto, después se busca la última coincidencia de ":00:" que ya estaría antes de "02:01".

Comment: Acabo de leerlo. Me parece perfecto.

Answer (score 3):

Disculpen, no se español muy bien, pero:

Si hay solo un ejemplo de dos (solo un ":00" y solo un ":02:01"), puede hace semajante asi (pseudocode):

```
const str Primero = ":00";
const str Segundo = ":02:01";
string s = "2:35:1F:99:0C:01:00:4C:00:01:2B:3E:0C:00:02:00:02:00:00:00:E7:03:07:00:61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45:02:01:00:00:00:00";
int primeroLugar = s.IndexOf(Primero);
int segundoLugar = s.IndexOf(Segundo);
string entre = s.Substring(primeroLugar, segundoLugar-primeroLugar);
```

### UPDATE

Porque hay muchas ":00", tal vez asi:

```
const str Primero = ":00";
const str Segundo = ":02:01";
string s = "2:35:1F:99:0C:01:00:4C:00:01:2B:3E:0C:00:02:00:02:00:00:00:E7:03:07:00:61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45:02:01:00:00:00:00";
int segundoLugar = s.IndexOf(Segundo);
string sMenos = s.Substring(0, segundoLugar);
int primeroLugar = sMenos.LastIndexOf(Primero);
string entre = sMenos.Substring(primeroLugar, segundoLugar-primeroLugar);
```

Comment: Pero :00: se repite en la cadena

Comment: ":02:01" solo una vez?

Comment: Sí ese dato es fijo

Comment: Hola B.Clay. He editado la pregunta para que se comprenda mejor el problema y las posibles soluciones a brindar.

Comment: Para tu nueva solución, no sé si sea relevante evaluar que `"00"` se encuentre antes de `"02:01"`.

Answer (score 2):

Creería que con la ayuda de @B.Clary Shannon encontré la respuesta. a continuación el código.

```
               const string Primero = ":00:";
                const string Segundo = ":02:01:";
               string s = "2:35:1F:99:0C:01:00:4C:00:01:2B:3E:0C:00:02:00:02:00:00:00:E7:03:07:00:61:4E:4E:45:54:54:45:02:01:00:00:00:00";
                int segundoLugar = s.IndexOf(Segundo);
                string sMenos = s.Substring(0, segundoLugar);
                int primeroLugar = sMenos.LastIndexOf(Primero);
                string entre = sMenos.Substring(primeroLugar, segundoLugar - primeroLugar);
                string CharName = entre.Substring(4);

 Console.WriteLine(CharName);
```